# How to fix jumpy scroll in Vue in v-for with elements being automatically added?

Tags: javascript, html, css, vue.js

[Screen recording](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GPsWz.jpg)

In the above video the same webapp in Safari, Chrome and Firefox.

After pressing start an infinite loop generates new tile, computed array places it "temporary" in the main array at a location determined by `window.scrollY`, waits 1 second, then adds this tile permanently to the array. Current `window.scrollY` is being updated every 8ms and is displayed at the top right corner.

What I do is after start I wait for at least 5 tiles to be added and then scroll down slowly without letting go for 50-100 pixels. As you can see in the video Safari handles it well, scroll behaves as expected. Chrome suddenly jumps scroll to +200 or so, and Firefox jumps to the end of the array.

You can disregard all `transition-group` animations and animation of each tile, disabling them didn't change anything. `ScrollTo` or anything similar is never used in the code.

`V-for` is used like this:

```
<div id="tileStack">
  <transition-group name="transitionStack" tag="ul">
    <TileItem 
      v-for="tile in tileStackWithGap"
      :key="tile.key
    />
  </transition-group>
</div>
```

with `tileStackWithGap` being the computed array with new tile sliced in.

All related CSS rules are:

```
html, body, ul {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

#tileStack {
  width: 100vw;
  padding: 40.5vh 0;
}

.tileMain {
  width: 30vh;
  max-width: calc(100vw - 4vh);
  height: 15vh;
  padding: 0px;
  margin: 2vh auto;
  border-radius: 3vh;
}

.tilePreview {
  width: 24vh;
  max-width: calc(80vw - 3.2vh);
  height: 12vh;
  border-radius: 2.4vh;
}
```

with `tilePreview` being applied to the "temporary" tile.

What can be causing this behaviour and is there a way to battle it?

Answer (score 1):

Turns out the behaviour was caused by scroll anchoring, which in my case did exactly the opposite. Can be turned of with `overflow-anchor: none`